# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have problem with mailChimp integration. On localhost all works good but on deploy i have error. `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')`. This is my interface

```
interface NewsletterFormValues {
  EMAIL: string;
}
```

and my function:

```
const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<NewsletterFormValues>();
  const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_URL as string;
  const { message, handleSubmit: mailChimpSubmit } = useMailChimpForm(url);
  const emailError = errors["EMAIL"];
  const onSubmit = (fields: NewsletterFormValues) => {
    mailChimpSubmit(fields as Params);
  };
```

and this is my input for email adress

```
<input
                    {...register("EMAIL", {
                      required: true,
                      pattern:
                        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                    })}
                    className="w-full lg:w-[458px] h-14 placeholder-black text-[16px] outline-0 py-[18px] pl-4 lg:mr-[24px] border-[1px] border-[#DDDDDC]"
                    placeholder="Email address"
                  />
```

Comment: Did you validate that the environment variable is being read properly? I'm guessing the useMailChimpForm function is being passed an undefined URL. Please share full trace of the error.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at handleSubmit (336-722198b56db31067.js:1:29916)
    at 10-346d7d40ac658ef0.js:1:21106
    at 336-722198b56db31067.js:1:227029

Comment: i miss environment variable thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_URL` (and therefore `url`) is `undefined`, which causes the error when the undefined `url` is passed to `useMailChimpForm`.